# How to build docker-image with environment variables while not pushing .env-file

Tags: node.js, gitlab, environment-variables, devops, gitlab-ci

Iam new to Dev-Ops and find myself a bit confused.
I have a node-project which starts a server. One endpoint of that server should write to a database. On my local machine I test this behavior with a local DB.
I created a .env.prod-file and a .env.dev-file to determine whether I use the local DB or my server DB (running on my server). I also read in blog posts that I should never ever push my .env-files to a remote repository.

Than I created a Dockerfile for building and shipping my application.

On my remote Gitlab-Repository I created a .gitlab-ci.yml which should build the docker-image from the Dockerfile every time there is a new commit to master.

But now I am faced with the issue that when I want to build the docker-image I need the .env.prod file but I should never push this file so GitLab has no access to it.

Is this described way an appropriate solution or do I do something entirely wrong(am I missing some core-concept in Dev-ops)?

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.7-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /usr/graphql-server
COPY package.json /usr/graphql-server/

RUN npm install
COPY ./ /usr/graphql-server

RUN npm run build
COPY ./ /usr/graphql-server

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

and the `npm run start:prod` does this:

`tsc && cross-env NODE_ENV=prod node dist/index.js`

That is how I determine which configuration to use (index.ts):

```
function getConfig(): void {
  let path;
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod') {
    path = `${__dirname}/../src/.env.prod`;
  } else {
    path = `${__dirname}/../src/.env.dev`;
  }
  dotenv.config({ path });
}
```

Comment: It's possible to store [environment variables as file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#custom-environment-variables-of-type-file) in gitlab. Could you provide your Dockerfile ?

Comment: Config values like db credentials should not be part of your image (and thus not bundled with it). Using configuration from environment is a good pattern. When you deploy your application, the corresponding runtime should handle the injection of those variables. Where do you run your containers eventually? BTW: Interacting with dotenv files programatically isn't best practice though. During prod, env should be published by some other process like the runtime...

Comment: I run the containers on my own hosted server. There I create a docker-compose.yml-File to run them. Is the docker-compose-File the more appropriate place to inject environment variables?

Comment: I tried a different approach and felt more satisfied with it.
In my Dockerfile I have now environment variables. These variables are used to start the node process acording to the enviroment. The docker environment variables are provided in my docker-compose.yml
@AndreasJägle is this what you intended

Comment: Yep! You don't need to have env vars in your Dockerfile though. The image/your code should read the values from env variables and when working with docker-compose, one way to pass them is putting them into the compose file. You can also have them set on the host as env and only pass the variable names, so you can use the same compose file on each system. See details here https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#pass-environment-variables-to-containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally thanks to @AndreasJägle I came up with a completely different solution for then what I first thought of.
I dont need a .env-file and dont use the described getConfig() method for this solution anymore. As well there is no need to store environment-variables in Gitlab.

First I now start my node process by passing environment variables at the end of the node command like `node dist/index.js variable1`.
This environment variable can be read at runtime: `const baseUrl = process.argv[2]`.
The baseUrl-variable can than be used to send requests to this certain url.

Second because I'am building my project using docker I have to inject the values for the environment-variables into my docker-image. For this I modified my dockerfile like this.

```
FROM node:12.7-alpine AS build

ENV BASE_URL=localhost
    
...

CMD ["sh", "-c", "node dist/index.js $BASE_URL"]
```

(note that localhost is the default value for the BASE_URL environment variable and will be overridden)

Finally I use the previously build image in a docker-compose file on my server and set the environment variable like this.

```
version: "3"

    services:
      test-service:
        image: my-image:latest
        container_name: 'my-container'
        environment:
          - BASE_URL=mydomain.com
```